# Is "Community" pushing themed questions now?

Tags: discussion

This night Community choose eight audio related questions to push in a row (ok, one HDD/WiFi question in between). Is this intentionally? If so has it been observed before? (I cannot remember to have noticed such a thing.)

[image]

Comment: I have seen this before. I seem to recall it is a way to publicize older questions - though i can't remember where I saw that mentioned. I only noticed it because one day I got a lot of rep on old answers.

Comment: I have never understood this "Community" thing. It seems to resurrect questions based on obsolete distributions or old hardware. Many of these seem to have been adequately answered (or ignored as appropriate), but abandoned by naive  users who never visit the site again.